# Liferay leave select-type custom field empty

Tags: liferay, custom-fields

I have some custom fields in Liferay which are displayed as selection lists. These fields are not mandatory so the user should be able to leave them blank. How can I achieve this? Now always the first value is selected by default. I tried to enter a blank line before the options in the "default value" field of the custom field configuration form, but it had no effect.

Comment: Why do you need a blank value? and for which module are you using the custom-field? So that we can try to give you a workaround. You can't have a blank line or value with only spaces, in the `Default Values` textarea, either you can use ` -- ` to denote blank or if numeric values than `-1` or `0` to mean blank.

Comment: I have custom fields for Users. I need blank values because these fields are optional, and I have no default values. For textual field I already set something like you suggested ('--select value--), but I was wondering if it is possible to simply leave it blank. The other field denotes years, so it is numeric, but 0 has no sense here. Maybe I should change it to text, and use the same workaround. Blank would look better, but if it is not possible, I must go this way...

Comment: same proble... i am getting null or default value of added custom attribute ..